# executeUpdate is not working after a loop

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to copy data from a database to another so I have the below code, the insertion inside the loop is perfect but the second insertion is not working and gives no error

```
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("select id,cardid,a2,a2b,a2c,a2e,a17,a11,a16,a15,a14,a20a from a");
            while (rs.next()){
                a=rs.getString(1);
                b=rs.getString(2);
                c=rs.getString(3);
                d=rs.getString(4);
                e=rs.getString(5);
                f=rs.getString(6); 
                g=rs.getString(7); 
                h=rs.getString(8);
                i=rs.getString(9);
                j=rs.getString(10);
                k=rs.getString(11);
                l=rs.getString(12);
                //sql="insert into rpttbl (empid) values ("+a+");";
                sql="insert into rpttbl (temp,empid,name,fname,gname,sname,jkind,jstatus,emplevel,emptitle"
                        + ",cert,pay,pos,except,cens,cuts,med,job,presd,outjob,other,iban) values ("+a+","+"\""+b+"\""+","+"\""+c+""
                        + "\""+","+"\""+d+"\""+","+"\""+e+"\""+","+"\""+f+"\""+","+"\""+g+"\""+","+"\""+h+"\""+","+"\""+i+"\""+""
                        + ","+"\""+j+"\""+","+"'visacard'"+","+"\""+k+"\""+","+"\""+l+"\""+","+"0"+","+"0"+","+"0"+","+"0"+""
                        + ","+"0"+","+0+","+0+","+"0"+","+"0"+");";
                rptStmt= conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
                rptStmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                //System.out.println("cccccc");
            }


            sql="insert into rpttbl (tax) values (111)";
            rptStmt= conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
            rptStmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            }
```

edit: I notice that only the last row of the table has tax=111

Comment: Did you read the documentation for [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String))?

Comment: yes, i did. But I didn't understand the problem

Comment: `prepareStatement(...)` returns a `PreparedStatement` and the documentation says you cannot use `executeUpdate(...)` on `PreparedStatement`s

Comment: I tried the code without prepareStatement and the same problem

Comment: Use `conCreate.createStatement()` instead of `conCreate.prepareStatement(sql)` and it should work.

Comment: The same problem. The second insertion dose not working

Comment: Do read a JDBC tutorial, though. The first statement should be a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement`, and you don't seem to close any resources.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've just notice that only the last row of the table has the tax value 111. How to make the insertion from the first row?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you use a `PreparedStatement` you should use placeholders for values (`?`). You are still concatenating user input into the SQL string which completely defies the use of a `PreparedStatement`. Don't do that. Read the JDBC tutorial for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: You need to use `executeUpdate()` **not**  `executeUpdate(sql)`

Comment: Do you want to update all rows? So that every row has tax=111?

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!
I used (update) instead of (insert)